# Value_type of a container template parameter

Tags: c++, std

In his keynote of this years Going Native [The Essence of C++](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/Opening-Keynote-Bjarne-Stroustrup) (go to 40:30) Bjarne Stroustrup gives the following code example:

```
template<typename C, typename V>
vector<Value_type<C>*> find_all(C& cont, V v) 
{
    vector<Value_type<C>*> res; 

    for (auto& x : cont) 
        if (x == v) 
            res.push_back(&x)

    return res;
}
```

This function is used to find all occurrences of a value in a container
and returns pointers to the found elements. The example from the video:

```
string m{"Mary had a little lamb"}; 
for (const auto p: find_all(m,'a')) // p is a char*
    if (*p != 'a')
        cerr << "string bug!\n";
```

My question is about **`Value_Type<C>*`**. Is there something like this in the standard 
library? I looked for it and didn't find it. How could this be implemented, if it's not in std?

Comment: @interjay You just have to watch the first 42 minutes or so :-) But you're right. I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know of this in the standard, but it's not hard to implement:

```
    template <class C>
    struct value_type
    {
       typedef typename C::value_type type;
    };

    template <class T, int N>
    struct value_type<T[N]>
    {
       typedef T type;
    };

    template <class T>
    struct value_type<T*>
    {
      typedef T type;
    };
```

and now you can use `typename value_type<C>::type` to access the type that a container contains.  If you have your own container you would like to use but it doesn't have a `value_type` typedef (and for whatever reason you can't change it) then you can simply specialize this struct for that container as well.

To avoid the `typename ...::type` you can do:

```
    template <class C>
    using Value_Type = typedef value_type<C>::type;
```

and now you just use `Value_Type<C>` everywhere.

**EDIT**
As stefan suggested in soon's answer, you can do this more easily with `std::begin` which is okay because any container you use/create you would want to be able to call `std::begin` and `std::end` on anyway:

```
    template <class C>
    using Value_Type = typename std::remove_reference<
        decltype(*std::begin(std::declval<
            typename std::add_lvalue_reference<C>::type>()))>::type;
```

This is much more concise, though it's gotten a little dense to read.  It's still better than the first option, this will require less boilerplate code for custom container types.

Comment: Slightly wrong: Add `typename std::remove_reference<` ...`>::type` around your decltype stuff ;-) Demo: http://ideone.com/bCF0qz

Comment: [Does not work with arrays](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0a0582b2710b362b)

Comment: @soon fixed it, `decltype(arr)` was returning `int [5]` whereas `std::begin` needs a reference `int (&)[5]`.

Comment: @GuyGreer Perfect, that's what I was trying this second :D Another demo: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/83d0a80070903c39

Comment: @stefan in your demo you have a stray `&` in `std::vector<Value_Type<C&>*> find_all(...)`, I don't know if this was intentional...

Comment: @GuyGreer Thanks. That was a stupid first try that somehow survived. [corrected demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c52968a65bd21df2)

Answer (score 3):

`Value_type<C>` is just a typedef for `C::value_type`. As far, as I know, there is no such typedef in standard library, but you could define it yourself:

```
template <class T>
using Value_type = typename T::value_type;

template<typename C, typename V>
std::vector<Value_type<C>*> find_all(C& cont, V v)
{
    std::vector<Value_type<C>*> res;

    for (auto& x : cont)
        if (x == v)
            res.push_back(&x);

    return res;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v{1, 2, 3, 3, 5};

    for(const auto x: find_all(v, 3))
    {
        std::cout << *x << std::endl;
    }
}
```

But, as suggested by @stefan, this will work with standard containers only. You could retrieve underlying type with using `std::begin` function(which is defined for arrays too), how it's implemented in @GuyGreer's answer

Comment: This is correct for standard containers, but e.g. not for arrays. Afaik, `std::begin` works with every sort of range. There's probably a nice way to get the underlying type from the iterator returned from `std::begin`.